# How can I update my UI using an observer?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, android-2.1-eclair

I've implemented a simple Observer pattern in a "hello world" style app.

I've got 2 buttons, which call `onStart()` and `onDestroy()` on a `Service`.

In the `onStart()` I register an observer and then get my observer to run a for loop calling `observe.update()` once every second for 10 seconds. This in turn calls an `update()` method in my service.

I'm trying to display some dummy data which gets returned, but I'm getting the following error :

```
11-26 23:21:12.829: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(676): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
        at com.jameselsey.observerpattern.LocalService.observe(LocalService.java:27)
        at obs.Stub$1.run(Stub.java:49)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I'm doing the following in my service :

```
public void observe(String message)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Log.d("TEST", "Inside observe() on service, value is " + message);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

After a bit of research, it seems I can't create a Toast message as this method doesn't run on the main UI thread.

Is there anyway I can spit out `message` onto my UI? I'm just looking to have it display on the activitiy, even a regular textView is OK.

Comment: Don't call onStart() and onDestroy() directly. That's incredibly bad.

Comment: Hi Falmarri, I have 2 buttons that are mapped onto methods in an activity, those activities call the onStart/onDestroy. Is that still bad? What is best?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are not supposed to show any UI. The only acceptable approach is to display a [notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) which can start an activity through an intent. Your service can also communicate with your UI using a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) or it can start an activity directly.

If somehow your activity gets called on a background thread, you can get it running on the main thread using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29). You should also get intimately familiar with [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in general.